# Binding with a class that derives from List<T>

Tags: .net, vb.net, binding, combobox, generic-list

How can I bind my `ComboBox` with a class that derives from `List(Of T)`? I have tried assigning the class instance directly to `ComboBox.DataSource`, which doesn't work. I have tried to assign the instance to `BindingSource.DataSource` too (and then assigning that `BindingSource` to `ComboBox.DataSource`), this one also doesn't update my `ComboBox` when new items are added to/removed from the List. Only the objects that existed in the List at the time of binding are shown.

The `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties of the `ComboBox` are properly set.

Here is my List class:

```
Public Class DrawingObjectsList
    Inherits List(Of DrawingObjectBase)
    ...
End Class
```

Here is the list instance:

```
Private mDOs As New DrawingObjectsList
```

Here's my `ComboBox` and accompanying `BindingSource` binding:

```
Dim WithEvents bsDOs As System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource
bsDOs.DataSource = mDOs
cboObjects.DataSource = Me.bsDOs
cboObjects.DisplayMember = "Name"
cboObjects.ValueMember = "ObjectID"
```

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: @KarlAnderson: Added my code above.

Comment: Did you try this: `cboObjects.DataSource = Me.bsDOs.DataSource`?

Comment: That would be funny if it works. After you are simply assigning the reference indirectly.